# Writing easily importable Wagtail elements, fields and pages

Tags: api, dry, wagtail

I have several websites based on **Wagtail** with Streamfield Models, Blocks and custom code for creating Bootstrap Carousels, Streamfields and simple blogs etc.  However each has a separate code base on GitHub, and solutions obviously combine models and template code.

If **I write** code implementing **new functionality** in one site, **how do I** manage it in such a way that I can **push that functionality to** all **my other sites**?

It seems this should be a problem that many developers face, but I am struggling to find a standard solution. I am conscious that the answer might require a whole course of knowledge but any pointers and guides would be gratefully received, or perhaps I am thinking about this problem in the wrong way?

Comment: Have you considered a separate package with a bunch of streamfield definitions? you could then pip install it directly from your GitHub repository. See https://github.com/springload/wagtailcommonblocks for an example

Comment: I had, but couldn't get my head around how it would work.  WagtailCommonBlocks is a great example though, thank you.  So I would clone my version of WagtailCommonBlocks within my main wagtail site and add it to that sites .gitignore,  then I can import blocks, page models and templates from the app?

Comment: You can move it to its own repository then do `pip install -e git://[github URL.git]#egg=egg_name`. https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/ is a good read on how to prepare a python package

Comment: That's a great way of rolling it out across my sites.  Really appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help close this down, my suggestion as per comments:

- separate the Streamfield block definitions into a pip-installable package a la github.com/springload/wagtailcommonblocks
- add the package to all your sites requirements txt as `git://[github URL.git]#egg=egg_name` (the equivalent of `pip install -e git://[github URL.git]#egg=egg_name`). Note: `egg_name` should be the name of your package.
  realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package is very good read on how to prepare a python package for publishing

Comment: Moved all my shared code into a separate wagtail app already and it works perfectly. Thanks.